# Firebase Cloud Functions - Realtime Database - Get parent node key

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get the key of parent node, from the snapshot. To confirm, i am getting the correct node data from the function below, when i print `snapshot.val()`, so the issue is not with the query, but i can't seem to find a way to get the key of the return snapshot.

```
/games
   |--{game_id} ==> get this id
         |---"alias":"123456" ==> from the snapshot returned by querying this
         |---"players":...
         |..... // other childs of game_id
```

Here is the cloudfunction code:

```
export const getGameIDFromCode = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    if (context.auth == null) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', 'You are not authorized to use this feature');
    }

    const code = data.code;
    const gamesRef = db.ref("/games");
    return gamesRef.orderByChild("alias").equalTo(code).once("value").then(snapshot => {

        if (snapshot.ref.parent != null) {
            // tried snapshot.key => returns "games"
            // tried snapshot.ref.key ==> returns "games"
            return snapshot.ref.parent.key;
        } else {
            return "Unable to find game_id for the code";
        }


    }).catch(error => {
        return error;
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code to this to work:

```
 return gamesRef.orderByChild("alias").equalTo(code).limitToLast(1).once("value").then(snapshot => {

        let gameId;

        snapshot.forEach(child => {
            gameId = child.key;
        })

        return gameId;

    }).catch(error => {
        return error;
    });
```

Comment: Yes it's returning the game_id as expected, but please note the alias is a unique code, so I only have one result. If you have multiple nodes that match the query, then you have to change the logic inside the foreach